# Longtable doesn't work well with geometry

Tags: header-footer, margins, longtable, fancyhdr, geometry

I would like to produce document with multiple longtables inside. I need to customize my headers with fancyhdr placing graphics inside it and modyfying page geometry. But then longtables have problems with flipping over the page. 
Here is an example of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0.5cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\headheight}{3cm}
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{1cm}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[C]{ \hspace*{-1.1cm} \fbox{\begin{picture}(500,300) \end{picture}}}

\noindent
Information:\\
\textbf{\textsc{John}}\\ 
\textbf{\textsc{Johnson}}\\ 
\textbf{\textsc{Firm A}}\\ 
\textbf{\textsc{54-427 Wrocław}}\\ 
\textbf{\textsc{phone}}\\ 



\begin{flushright}
    \textbf{Firm B}\\
\textbf{Adress}\\
\textbf{234-567-981}\\
\textbf{Andrew Smith}\\

\end{flushright}

\begin{longtable}{lrrr}
    \textbf{Funkcjonalność}\\ \hline
    \endhead
    \textbf{Funkcjonalność}\\ \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline \\
    \endfoot
    \hline \\
    \endlastfoot
    Wyszukiwanie i filtrowanie &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Połączenia danych &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Kod kreskowy &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Wersjonowanie plików &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Import/eksport do Excela &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Statystyki pracy użytkowników &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Kopia zapasowa codziennie na zewnętrzny ftp &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Konto master & 2$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Użytkownik & 3$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Klient & 4$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Suma użytkowników &   &  &0 zł\\ 

\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{lrrr}
    \textbf{Moduły}\\ \hline
    \endhead
    \textbf{Moduły}\\ \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline \\
    \endfoot
    \hline \\
    \endlastfoot
    Wyszukiwanie i filtrowanie &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Połączenia danych &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Kod kreskowy &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Wersjonowanie plików &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Import/eksport do Excela &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Statystyki pracy użytkowników &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Kopia zapasowa codziennie na zewnętrzny ftp &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Konto master & 2$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Użytkownik & 3$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Klient & 4$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Suma użytkowników &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Wielkość przestrzeni dyskowej & 2$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
OCR wizytówek &   & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Wysyłanie seryjnych e-maili &   & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Indywidualny import/eksport danych &   & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Udostępnianie wybranych danych online &   & 0 &0 zł\\ 

\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{lrrr}
    \textbf{Wdrożenie}\\ \hline
    \endhead
    \textbf{Wdrożenie}\\ \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline \\
    \endfoot
    \hline \\
    \endlastfoot
    Wyszukiwanie i filtrowanie &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Połączenia danych &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Kod kreskowy &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Wersjonowanie plików &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Import/eksport do Excela &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Statystyki pracy użytkowników &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Kopia zapasowa codziennie na zewnętrzny ftp &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Konto master & 2$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Użytkownik & 3$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Klient & 4$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Suma użytkowników &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Wielkość przestrzeni dyskowej & 2$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
OCR wizytówek &   & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Wysyłanie seryjnych e-maili &   & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Indywidualny import/eksport danych &   & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Udostępnianie wybranych danych online &   & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Wdrożenie pierwszego stanowiska & 1$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Wdrożenie dodatkowych stanowisk & 1$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Dojazd & 1$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Godziny szkoleniowe & 1$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Dodatkowe koszty &   &  &0 zł\\ 

\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{lrrr}
    \textbf{Płatności}\\ \hline
    \endhead
    \textbf{Płatności}\\ \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline \\
    \endfoot
    \hline \\
    \endlastfoot
    Wyszukiwanie i filtrowanie &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Połączenia danych &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Kod kreskowy &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Wersjonowanie plików &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Import/eksport do Excela &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Statystyki pracy użytkowników &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Kopia zapasowa codziennie na zewnętrzny ftp &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Konto master & 2$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Użytkownik & 3$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Klient & 4$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Suma użytkowników &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Wielkość przestrzeni dyskowej & 2$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
OCR wizytówek &   & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Wysyłanie seryjnych e-maili &   & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Indywidualny import/eksport danych &   & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Udostępnianie wybranych danych online &   & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Wdrożenie pierwszego stanowiska & 1$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Wdrożenie dodatkowych stanowisk & 1$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Dojazd & 1$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Godziny szkoleniowe & 1$\times$  & 0 &0 zł\\ 
Dodatkowe koszty &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Cena modułów &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Cena wdrożenia &   &  &0 zł\\ 
Rateczki &   &  &0 zł\\ 

\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Sorry for some non-english words, but I hope it doesn't matter what's inside.

EDIT:
I attach the image that should be in header to approach to original problem.
[Header of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC772.jpg)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Not sure what the problem is. Please elaborate. Also, did you run this a few times?  `longtable` requires multiple passes to complete.  Since I do not have your figures, I had to use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`, but the output seemed fine.

Comment: the text  isn't a problem but the missing image is as it means we get different page breaks. Can you replace it by something like `\fbox{\begin{picture}(100,100)\end{picture}}` with the size chosen to get the same behaviour?

Comment: I see the problem. Image in my header is quite high. I have edited code to simulate my situation.

Comment: I solved my problem by using eso-pic package and setting image as a background. I don't mess up with header height any more and then longtable works well. 
Thanks for hints!

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem of timing. You shouldn't be setting `\headheight` after `\begin{document}`.

Without knowing the height of your picture, I've had satisfying results with

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm,headheight=90pt}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[C]{\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=3cm]{naglowek.jpg}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
```

This should be entirely in the preamble. With `\makebox[0pt]{...}` you're free to set whatever width for the image, without having to guess. The necessary `\headheight`, that should be specified in `\geometry` will be notified in the log file, if the one set is insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem is that your page dimensions are inconsistent, when I run your example I get

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (85.35826pt): 
 Make it at least 636.1754pt.
```

when `fancyhdr` gives that warning it means what it says. There is more stuff in the headline than the allotted space and so it pushes down and confuses `longtable` which doesn't know that the page header has leaked into the page body area. Without any information on the actual size of the image I can't really adjust the example.